# Looking for Ways to Only Read Specific Rows from a CSV File into SAS

Tags: sas

Is there a way to read specific rows of a CSV file into SAS or to limit the number of rows being read from a CSV file into SAS? For example, if you had a data set with 1000 rows, but you just wanted to read in the first 800 rows, is there a way to do so? Any input regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

*Copied from comments*

I was wondering if there was a way to do so in the `proc import` procedure. My code is as follows:

```
options MSGLEVEL=I;
options validvarname=v7;
proc import 
  out=one 
  datafile='/home/user/Assessment/test_1.csv'
  DBMS=csv
  replace
  ; 
  getnames=yes;
run;
```

Comment: A CSV file is a TEXT file and not a dataset.  Why do you only want to read some of the lines?  Is it because the later lines are not actually part of the data and reading them would cause PROC IMPORT to make the wrong guesses about how to read the actual data fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to read specific rows of a CSV file is to use the [`FIRSTOBS` and `OBS`](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat481/book/export/html/641) options in the `SET` statement:

```
data mydata;
   infile "myfile.csv" delimiter=',' firstobs=1 obs=800;
   input var1 var2 var3 ... ;
run;
```

You can also use the `STOP` statement in data steps:

```
data mydata;
   infile "myfile.csv" delimiter=',' ;
   input var1 var2 var3 ... ;
   if _n_ <= 800 then output;
   else stop;
run;
```

The if *n* <= 800 statement tells SAS to output rows only if the observation number is less than or equal to 800. The else stop statement tells SAS to stop reading the file after the 800th row.

Both of these methods will read in only the specified rows from the CSV file, and will ignore any rows after the specified limit.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @Ethan R! Actually, I was wondering if there was a way to do so in the proc import procedure. My code is as follows: 

options MSGLEVEL=I;

options validvarname=v7;

proc import out=one

datafile='/home/user/Assessment/test_1.csv'

DBMS=csv replace;

getnames=yes;

run;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but try OPTION OBS=.

e.g.

```
option obs=800;

proc import code.....

option obs=max;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of observations written by the DATA STEP that PROC IMPORT generates by setting the OBS= system option before calling the step. Note the OBS= will actually limit the number of lines READ from the CSV file so the header row is included in that count of observations.  So if you set OBS=800 then it will read 800 lines and create a dataset with 799 observations.

But if you also don't want PROC IMPORT to use the WHOLE file when making its GUESS about how to define the variables you need to use the GUESSINGROWS statement.  Otherwise the information in the data lines after 800 will impact how PROC IMPORT defines the variables.

So to create a dataset with the first 800 observations of the data in the CSV file you could use code like:

```
options obs=801;
proc import 
  out=one 
  datafile='/home/user/Assessment/test_1.csv'
  DBMS=csv
  replace
  ; 
  getnames=yes;
  guessingrows=801;
run;
options obs=max;
```

So in conclusion yet another reason to skip the PROC IMPORT step and just write the data step to read the file yourself.